Realtime Code Execution in .Net Nanoframework
I have noticed that .net Nanoframework is going well with support for many microcontrollers allowing entire code to be written in c#.
My question is if .net Nanoframework could be used to run 'Real-time' tasks. This would mean that task must complete in a predefined time with minimum variation/jitter. Realtime recurring tasks are a key need for industrial applications where controllers are expected to run certain tasks in real-time mode while other less important tasks could run at their pace.
As an example assume that I need to read/change a GPIO state of a microcontroller every 250us, with minimum possible variation between the cycles, is this something achieve-able with Nanoframework? Is this something on the roadmap?
Thanks,

Absolutely! That can be accomplished from the early days.
For time critical tasks, like the one you've described, the code that deals with the GPIO read/change should be written in C/C++. Through Interop (pretty much common to the full .NET) you expose to C# whatever API it makes sense to have (set configs, read something from the GPIO, etc.
Check this blog post and find a sample in the .NET nanoFramework Samples repo.

Many Thanks Jose, your work is inspirational.  Could you also create an example where you run a hard real time recurring task in c++ (LED Blinking at 1000Hz with no jitter). while running other non realtime code in c#. Would this require using a Nanoframework Thread or a different approach. How would the function be interrupted if it overruns it's hard execution window?

Thank you for your kind words. :)
The code blinking the LED could be a trivial PWM (for example). Or a loop writing GPIO output state (not so efficient). The latter would run on its own RTOS thread. It's up to the RTOS configurations to ensure that every task runs on its alloted time slice. The CLR and execution engine run on its own RTOS thread.
